# Android webrtc crash

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing a webrtc video chat application, it is working fine but I get this error from time to time:

```
10-19 14:06:33.058 2734-4156/com.thirdeyegen.developers E/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.VP8.Encoder] ERROR(0x90000006)
signalError(omxError 0x90000006, internalError -2147483648)
10-19 14:06:33.058 2734-4155/com.thirdeyegen.developers E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x90000006, actionCode 0, while in state 6
10-19 14:06:33.059 2734-4166/com.thirdeyegen.developers E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoEncoder: deliverOutput failed
10-19 14:06:33.060 2734-4166/com.thirdeyegen.developers E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoEncoder: java.lang.IllegalStateException
HardwareVideoEncoder: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2568)
    at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoEncoder.deliverEncodedImage(HardwareVideoEncoder.java:488)
    at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoEncoder.access$100(HardwareVideoEncoder.java:34)
    at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoEncoder$1.run(HardwareVideoEncoder.java:477)
10-19 14:06:33.061 2734-4166/com.thirdeyegen.developers E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoEncoder: deliverOutput failed
HardwareVideoEncoder: java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-19 14:06:33.062 2734-4166/com.thirdeyegen.developers E/org.webrtc.Logging: HardwareVideoEncoder: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2568)
    at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoEncoder.deliverEncodedImage(HardwareVideoEncoder.java:488)
    at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoEncoder.access$100(HardwareVideoEncoder.java:34)
    at org.webrtc.HardwareVideoEncoder$1.run(HardwareVideoEncoder.java:477)
```

I thougt thats because I am enabling both vp8 and v264 encoders so I turned the v246 off the error stopped for a while and now happened again, anyone can know why

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this answer will fit for everyone but it worked in my case, I updated the webrtc to the latest, the crash is gone now

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used 30FPS and after I decreased it to 3FPS it worked.
I will be glad for some updates after you try it.

Comment: It’s for screen mirroring. 3fps is more then enough in that case.

Comment: Well, I'm getting this error only with two devices, Galaxy S8 and note 5.
The rest are ok, is it also your case?

Comment: I am not getting this error anymore since I updated my webrtc version to the latest, but when I was  getting this error I got it with all devices in production in the hand of users x(